# Faster asyncIterator for generating large csv files in deno

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, export-to-csv, deno

## Fast way of writing large csv-file in deno?

I am trying to parse an Input file and generate a `.csv` File as output.

So far it is working fine but the writing takes forever. My question is: How can I speed up the writing of the file? Is has about 1.000.000 lines as output.

### minimal example Code of current (slow) implementation

```
// generate a really long array to simulate input
const data = []

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  data.push({plz: '12345', strasse: 'Teststrasse'})
}


async function* asyncIterator(data: any): AsyncGenerator<any> {
  for (const entry of data) {
    yield entry;
  }
}

async function writeCSV(data: any[]): Promise<void> {
  const file = await Deno.open('./test.csv', {write: true, create: true});

  await writeCSVObjects(file, asyncIterator(data), {header: ['plz', 'strasse']});
  file.close();
}
```

I already had a hard time wrapping my head around this `asyncIterator` thing.

I would guess what is making this slow, is the constant yielding of the generator function? Is there a way of batch processing that would make this faster

MISC: I am using the standard [csv-library](https://deno.land/x/csv@v0.8.0/mod.ts) and [this](https://deno.land/x/csv@v0.8.0/mod.ts?s=writeCSVObjects) method from the library.

Comment: I tried using [csv-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer) from npm. It is significantly faster than the deno csv-library you are using.

Comment: @RickyMo Thank you for your suggestion! I was able to use csv-writer from npm and it's SO much faster (pretty much instant).

I am still interested how I could make my code version faster but for anybody searching I will include this little snippet for my working code:

`import {createObjectCsvWriter} from 'npm:csv-writer';`
and then
`const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({path: ZIELDATE,header: [
      {id: 'id', title: 'id'},
      {id: 'strasse', title: 'strasse'},
      {id: 'plz', title: 'plz'},
    ],
  });

  return await csvWriter.writeRecords(d);
`

Comment: You don't need an asynchronous iterator just a basic iterator because the function only uses `yield`, it doesn't use `await`

Comment: The links you provided don’t point to Deno’s standard library (`/std`). Those links point to some community module (`/x` hosts community/third-part code). The standard library includes very performant CSV tools. Here’s a link to a how-to-use example for streaming serialization: https://deno.land/std@0.192.0/csv/mod.ts?s=CsvStringifyStream#example_0

Comment: @jsejcksn Oh wow! Thank you! I just noticed that. Don't know how that happened but I am very thankful for your hint there. I guess I won't be needing an asyncIterator then...

Comment: @jsejcksn do you mind posting your latest comment as an answer?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488682/faster-asynciterator-for-generating-large-csv-files-in-deno/76597878#comment134972342_76488682) @mfulton26 [Posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597878/438273)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links you provided don’t point to Deno’s standard library ([`/std`](https://deno.land/std)). Those links point to some community module ([`/x`](https://deno.land/x) hosts community/third-party code). The standard library includes very performant CSV tools. Here’s a link to a how-to-use example for streaming serialization (I'm inlining it below in case the link ever breaks or points to a different resource in the future):

https://deno.land/std@0.192.0/csv/mod.ts?s=CsvStringifyStream#example_0

```ts
import { CsvStringifyStream } from "https://deno.land/std@0.192.0/csv/csv_stringify_stream.ts";
import { readableStreamFromIterable } from "https://deno.land/std@0.192.0/streams/readable_stream_from_iterable.ts";

const file = await Deno.open("data.csv", { create: true, write: true });
const readable = readableStreamFromIterable([
  { id: 1, name: "one" },
  { id: 2, name: "two" },
  { id: 3, name: "three" },
]);

await readable
  .pipeThrough(new CsvStringifyStream({ columns: ["id", "name"] }))
  .pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream())
  .pipeTo(file.writable);
```